# How to move Arial Hindi font from Windows 10 to Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, fonts, windows-server-2008-r2

I am working on a software product which has the functionality of generating MS Word reports using an MS Word template containing multiple merge fields.

The templates are stored in our application and are used by our clients when generating word reports (documents) on their computers. The issue is that the templates are usually designed in our development machines, which run Windows 8.1/10 and some of our clients are still running older versions of Windows.

That is why some of them have problems with the way the resulting documents are displayed. In this particular case, a client has issues generating a Word document with Hindi fonts. The template uses the standard Arial font and in Windows 10 it is displayed correctly, if the Hindi language is installed.

In Windows Server 2008 R2, however, the fonts are not displayed, and, as far as I could tell from the Internet, we only have the option to install a language pack for changing the Windows UI (it is unclear to me whether that would affect the way the fonts are displayed in MS Office).

Is there a way to copy the font from Windows 10 and install it on the client's Windows Server 2008 R2? Are the font systems between the two OSes compatible?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the windows font folder and then copy the font you want (Information on location of font folder and how to copy it: https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-10&faq=50 )

Then you can subsequently move the font to windows machine and install it by clicking the install button after double click to open the font file.

The font format are all the same

However, it should be noted that Arial fonts are [copyrighted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial).